# Installing aubio Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, pip, installation, python-wheel, aubio

I'm trying to pip install **aubio package to Python** on **64-bit windows 10**.

The problem seems to be that I can't build the wheel.

I get a dialogue box saying `"the program can't start because mspdb140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."`

Not exactly sure which program it is even referring to...

I've downloaded **Visual C++ 14.0** and the **aubio zip** files which I think are what it's telling me I need: I've tried pip installing and have downloaded **Visual C++ 14.0** and the **aubio zip** files which is what I think I need.

Here's the final error code I get:

```
Command "C:\Users\danci\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\danci\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
d5772nkl\\aubio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\danci\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
z8g1pk58-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\danci\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
build-d5772nkl\aubio\
```

Also, about halfway through installation I get this:

```
File "C:\Users\danci\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-
d5772nkl\aubio\python\lib\gen_external.py", line 108, in get_c_declarations
  raise Exception("preprocessor output is empty:\n%s" % err_output)
Exception: preprocessor output is empty:
b''

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for aubio
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems something is missing to your setup. To compile a python extension on windows, you will need the compiler that was used to build your python binary.

See this page about windows compiler to find out the correct version to use: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: By this you mean Visual C++ 14.0 for 64-bit windows, right? I've already downloaded that. Edited post to say "visual c++" not just "c++".